# HTTPS equivalent of WebRequest.CreateHttp on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have some C# code in a Windows Phone app...

```
WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.CreateHttp("http://bing.com");
```

is it possible to make this use HTTPS instead? There's no CreateHttps, and no obvious flags for me to fiddle with.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried following?

```
WebRequest wrq = WebRequest.Create("https://bing.com");
```

Notice that the url uses HTTPS scheme. I believe this should just work fine. Did you run into some issue with this method?

Answer (score 1):

Note you should not use CreateHttp in your app code!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382776%28v=vs.95%29.aspx